# How limit user connection?

Tags: plugins, users

I'm searching a way to limit my users to open at most 1 page a time. How can I obtain it without checking manually the user ID and build a plugin that check if that user is already online?

My aim is to deny a user from connecting to my website from two locations together (e.g. PC and Tablet).

Comment: I don't think there is a way to reliably do this, after all HTTP is a stateless protocol, how would you tell the difference between the user clicking on a link or a user middle clicking to open it as a second tab. Anything you find will be easily circumvented, or have unexpected consequences ( e.g. locking people out as they move around on their phone and their IP changes, or universities where only 1 person can view the page as they all share an IP, note that a lot of ISPs are using CGNAT to get around limited IP4 addresses too )

Comment: Netflix count user device. I'm thinking to compare <userId, Ip> in order to count the user sessions..

Comment: Netflix uses video streams and a browser plugin to determine that, the browsing interface isn't limited that way, you won't be able to replicate it in pure JS/HTML https://tomjn.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/Screen-Shot-2017-08-11-at-01.33.27.png

Comment: WP tracks sessions of logged in users, but that will tell you basic information about how many login cookies there are. It can't be used to make sure the user only has 1 page open rather than 20 in the same browser

Answer (score 1):

There is no foolproof method to do this, and I would note that you will not be able to cache pages for performance if you try this

### Force The User to Only be able to open a single page, no tabs, no other devices/browsers

This isn't possible, and the few measures that try to do this are trivial to bypass. Usually they're bypassed by accident by the user, who never realises it happened to begin with.

To do this, all your browser tabs will need to cross communicate. This won't work across browsers, or if JS fails, or JS is turned off. It's also possible every tab will detect each other and all tabs will lock out. Browser support for this will be limited. It won't be a WordPress based solution

### Force User Sessions Per Device

This is also not foolproof, there is no guarantee, but it's a little easier

```
$sessions = wp_get_all_sessions();
if ( count( $sessions ) > 1 ) {
    // more than 1 session, logout somewhere else to resume
}
```

Note that this:

- relies on the auth cookie WP uses
- the user must be logged in
- if your site is not https anybody can steal the cookie and share the session
- users can copy paste the cookie out of the dev tools and insert it into browsers on other devices, nothing you do can stop this
- Once a user reaches the page, they can logout in another tab, and open it on another device, giving them the page but on 2 devices

### A Note on IP tracking

This will not work, and give highly unpredictable results.

For example, NAT makes everything on a local network share a single IP. As would a proxy or VPN. ISPs are also experimenting with or using CGNAT, so millions of users may be sharing a small subset of IPv4 addresses, leading to unpredictable results.

You'll also lock out people tethering or using mobile phones. As they move around across cell phone masts their IPs might change, triggering the multiple screen detection system you're building.

### A Fundamental Problem

- cmd+s/ctrl+s/file->save as
- the print screen key
- Screen sharing in Hangouts/Skype/Zoom/FB Live/Twitch/etc/etc

You can very easily invest a huge amount of time in this only to find that somebody sidestepped it with something trivial. E.g. when spending weeks building advanced anti-theft systems to stop people right click saving an image, only to find that dragging and dropping it on to the desktop worked fine.